# Request for some other links on userprofile page of area51 as on SO or MSO

Tags: feature-request, area-51, hyperlinks

For example, In area51 when we click on the username and go to our profile page, then there is no other way to go back to the homepage ie, on `area51.stackexchange.com`.
So, there should be other links on user profile page as in other websites like stackoverflow and metastackoverflow.
As SO and meta and other websites are having header part which is viewed on each page of website, area51 should have also such header part.

Answer (score 3):

Every page on Area51 has the Area51 logo. Click that if you want to go back to the home page.

Comment: Ok.. But it can also have other links as on SO or MSO

Answer (score -1):

There is an arrow in the upper left of your browser window. It is pointing to the left side. Click it! You can do that several times.